# Retrieve particular field from serialized data

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Suppose I have following data :

```
a:1:{s:4:"date";a:3:{s:2:"mm";s:2:"12";s:2:"dd";s:2:"06";s:2:"yy";s:4:"1991";}}
```

I want the value of `mm` and `dd` from that serialized string.

I have following query to retrieve above data :

```
$birthday = "select meta_key, meta_value from $wpdb->usermeta where meta_key='pie_date_5'";

$user_birthday = $wpdb->get_results($birthday);

foreach($user_birthday as $ubday){
    $ubd = $ubday->meta_value; echo $ubd;
    echo json_decode($ubd[0]->mm);

}
```

I am not able to do that simple thing. Please help me out.

Comment: That's not JSON, that's serialized data! What do you want to do in Layman's terms?

Comment: I want to get month and date from that.

Comment: Thats not a json string its serialized string you need to use `unserialize()`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `unserialize` instead of `json_decode` because it's a **serialized string**.

So you could try something like this:

```
$user_birthday = 'a:1:{s:4:"date";a:3:{s:2:"mm";s:2:"12";s:2:"dd";s:2:"06";s:2:"yy";s:4:"1991";}}'; //the serialized string you get from your query

$upday = unserialize( $user_birthday );


echo $upday['date']['mm'] . PHP_EOL;
echo $upday['date']['dd'];
```

**EDIT:** If you want to read **all properties** from the `$upday` array you could use a `foreach`-loop

```
foreach ( $upday['date'] as $key => $value ) :
    echo $key . ' = ' . $value . PHP_EOL;
endforeach;
```

Comment: @Twix Is this answer helpful your you?